# SQL Server Grouped Outer Query with evaluating SubQuery

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I would like to run a single query that will produce an aggregated result.
I have the following Query that evaluates the Price Column and Pieces Column to Produce a result.  See below:

```
Select  Case When [Price]/[PIECES] < 10 Then 'Low Value'
             Else 
        Case When [Price]/[PIECES] >= 10 Then 'High Value'
             End
        End
AS [High/Low] 
FROM [tbl1]
```

Then I would like to take the result of the above query (substituting the values from above query in the [High/Low Value by Piece] column in the below query) and aggregate the data by [High/Low Value by Piece].  See below:

```
SELECT [High/Low Value by Piece], Sum([Pieces]) as Pieces, Sum([Price]) as Price 
FROM [tbl1]
Group by [High/Low Value by Piece]
Order by [High/Low Value by Piece]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your case statement has too many syntax errors. After fixing those you can directly use the `case` statement in `select` and `group by` something like this.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN [Price] / [PIECES] < 10 THEN 'Low Value'
         WHEN [Price] / [PIECES] >= 10 THEN 'High Value'
       END           AS [High/Low],
       Sum([Pieces]) AS Pieces,
       Sum([Price])  AS Price
FROM   [tbl1]
GROUP  BY CASE
            WHEN [Price] / [PIECES] < 10 THEN 'Low Value'
            WHEN [Price] / [PIECES] >= 10 THEN 'High Value'
          END
```

Comment: Hi NoDisplayName,  this works great and seems pretty straight forward.  Thank you so much.  This results in 3 seconds where in Access was taking 34 seconds.